# Scroll to an element after click action is complete

Tags: jquery

I am clicking on a button and reloading the same page with new content. Once the reloading is complete, I want to scroll the document all the way down. How can I do this using jQuery?

```
 $('#loadBtn').click(function () {
       //some logic
        window.location = url;
        window.scrollBy(0, $(document).height())
    });
```

The problem is that scrollBy is getting called before the page is reloaded. I tried chaining after the click event like below, but the scroll is happening after every 'ready' event.

```
 $('#loadBtn').click(function () {
           //some logic
            window.location = url;        
        }).on('ready',function() {
         window.scrollBy(0, $(document).height())
  });
```

My question is, how do I reload the page, wait for it to load and then scroll the document? Thanks!

Comment: you have to do this in the other page where you redirect to.

Comment: It's actually the same page, but with a different query parameter. I think my wording is not right..I will fix it

Comment: But also, if you reload the page the script will be again executed. So everything after `window.location = ...` will not execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest thing that you could do is using #something in url.

```
 window.location = url+'#id_ef_element_you_scroll_to';
```

And on the 2nd page just find any html tag that you can add id for example

```
<div id='id_ef_element_you_scroll_to'> ... </div>
```